# unable to Accept AzureRmMarketplaceTerms powershell

Tags: json, azure, powershell

I've got a strange one here, well I think it's strange. I've been trying to do a deployment using powershell calling some json files, however i get the following error:

> Get-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms : Offer with PublisherId: {0} and OfferId:
>   {1} not found. If this offer has been created recently, please allow
>   upto 30 minutes for this offer to be available for  Purchase. If error
>   persists, contact support.

The command i run to accept the terms is the same as the one I use on the different images, which works perfectly:

```
Get-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms -Publisher "MicrosoftWindowsServer" -Product "WindowsServer" -Name "2012-R2-Datacenter"
    | Set-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms -Accept
```

If I try ot run the install without accepting the terms i get the below message:

> Error: Code=BadRequest; Message=Offer with PublisherId:
>   MicrosoftWindowsServer, OfferId: WindowsServer cannot be purchased due
>   to validation errors.  See details for more information.[{"Legal terms
>   have not been accepted for this item on this subscription. To accept
>   legal terms using PowerShell, please use Get-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms
>   and  Set-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms
>   API(https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=862451)

Any idea how I can get past this?

Comment: Any more question?

Answer (score 0):

When you create Azure resource through deployment using PowerShell you do not accept the terms that while accepting them in the Azure Portal. Then you will get the error you showed.

The PowerShell command that you showed:

```
Get-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms -Publisher "MicrosoftWindowsServer" -Product "WindowsServer" -Name "2012-R2-Datacenter" | Set-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms -Accept
```

It's a way to accept the terms when you execute the Azure deployment. For more details, see [Accepting Azure Marketplace terms in PowerShell](https://www.nblabs.net/2017/12/20/accepting-azure-marketplace-terms-powershell/). Good luck!

Comment: what kind of BS is that? you need to accept marketplace term before deploying either way. why do you copy paste his cmd?

Comment: I said his command worked is a way to accept the terms to execute the deployment.

Comment: no, you need to execute this (once) before you deploy either way. it doesnt have to be a deployment.

Comment: Hi I had to change the api to a neeer one, from 2017-03-30 to 2018-01-07

Comment: Do you still use PowerShell?